# CRUD UI like admin screen

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a requirement to create one table that has check box enabled and reads data from gateway server. This screen have add, update and delete option on top of that.

On click of add dialog box should open and there will be entries like name, id, start date, end date, message.

As you can know to create new data add button is used. In case of some correction update is used that will read existing data on select of single check box. Delete can used for single or multiple.

Please help me in the dialog box form structure and better layout or using fragment to show xml view instead of Javascript coding that will support all devices and all along with the functionality using JSON and odata.

That will be much appreciated.

Thanks and regards

RK

Comment: and what did you try before coming to SO?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the question is, but if it's how to do it best a CRUD UI5 app, I usually build a Master/Detail floorplan with a Read only view and an Edit/New view on the detail side, then you should be able to structure the views to use the same OData model and you can easily flip between Read view and the Edit view.

Align the routes in manifest, create 3 targets, Read/Edit/Create, and instead of navigating with routes when changing data like
`oRouter.navTo()`, navigate using targets `oRouter.getTargets().display()` and bind the new view with the previously fetched data, once data has been changed and submitted, navigate back to the Read view which should display the updated data.

For Delete, just create a delete button on the detail action bar, for multiple deletion you have many options how to achieve it, depends how you want it to work.

OData V2/V4 allows you this flexibility without much manual coding. For more information you could refer to SAP's CRUD template in WebIDE, but my suggestion would be to only use it as a reference, not to build you actual app.

Comment: Hi Jefer, Do you have any sample program in a zip file? Please share with me using git I will check.

Comment: Hi Ram, as I mentioned, there are many ways to do what you're asking, and a good initial reference for you would be the CRUD template from SAP in WebIDE.